# VSTS OData - get comments from Work Item

Tags: odata, azure-devops, powerbi

I am trying to query the VSTS OData endpoint from Power BI to get the comments from [Discussion] section inside a Work Item.
It seems that this [Discussion] child entity is not exposed in the data model
(as described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/report/extend-analytics/data-model-analytics-service?view=vsts)

Does anyone know if it can be accessed from OData query or in any other way?

P.S.
Another way to do it may potentially be adding a custom text field inside a Work Item and moving all comments there, however, I am not sure if these fields are exposed in OData endpoint as well and can be accessed by means of querying.
I would be really grateful if anyone could share any information on that topic as well.

Comment: It seems even in power BI, the Discussion section (System.History field) can not be used neither.